# Apply the same bash script to multiple folders?

Tags: bash, directory, cat

I have a simple bash script that takes all `.md` files of the current folder and merge them into a new file:

```
for f in *.md; do cat "$f"; echo; done > output.txt;
```

It works well. Now I'd like to extend this script to takes a bunch of directory as parameters and combine all the md files of all these directories into one new file. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just add multiple folders:

```
for f in folder1/*.md folder2/*.md ... ; do cat "$f"; echo; done > output.txt;
```

Comment: Edited my code, I actually add a "echo;" between each file to add new lines. So I do need a for loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this,

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.md" -exec cat {} \; > output.txt
```

Searches for the `.md` files inside the current and the sub-directories  and execute the cat command on all those founded files. Finally it stores the output to a text file.

For two separate folders, you may try this,

```
find /path/folder1 /path/folder2 -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.md" -exec cat {} \; > output.txt
```